# Webapp to search paintings

Tags: gratis, images, search-engine

I am thinking of a painting but can't remember its title nor the painter.

I tried Google Images but it is not adapted:

[image]

Is there a painting search engine where I can search paintings:

- By year (for instance 1900~1920)
- By style (for instance impressionism)
- By topic (for instance portrait, pastoral, war, vanitas)
- By dominant colors (for instance green and blue)
- By color of background (for instance dark)
- By represented person (for instance Jean de Dinteville)
- By place (for instance Gare du Nord)

or at least a few of these.

Requirement:

- Free to use
- Thumbnails
- Contains most of the famous paintings *(let's define famous paintings as paintings that more than 100k persons in the world have heard about)*

Comment: Nicolas, google 'catalogue paintings' turns up lost of results, but I have not investigated whether they are useful. A job for a rainy afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

[Your Paintings - BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/arts/yourpaintings/paintings/search) would be a good choice for your work. It has 212,144 number of paintings in its database. You ca search paintings by:

- Things in the painting
- People in the painting
- Place
- Event
- Painting style
- Painting type
- Artist

It's free to use and it shows thumbnails also.

Comment: Awesome! But it is a pity that it only covers the UK's national collection.